# Upvote and downvote count inconsistency

Tags: support, downvotes, upvotes

When I upvoted a question initially, it was a question with 2 points.
After upvoting the question turned into 3.

> [image]

I realized it was not my question; I downvoted the question.
The points to the question turned to 1, and I expected the points should be reverted to the initial stage that was 2 points.

[image]

> First I doubt it was multiple users, but it is still the same when I repeat the steps.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Changing your vote (upvote) into a downvote will remove the upvote (-1) and then add a downvote (-1) adding up to -2

Comment: Yes, math works like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You down-voted the question. 2-1 = 1

If you wanted to remove your upvote, just click on the upvote button again to undo.